# C basic increasing/decreasing issue in for loop

Tags: c

just undertaking one online course, trying to make an assignment for something like reverse triangle. I am able to this in python, but for some reason in C it is not working for me, specifically the part of the for loop, where should be decreasing the k value. Tried it also in other blank project, just to verify the issue, but so far it was not working for me. Increasing (j loop) is working, decreasing (k loop) for some reason is not (also with all syntax options: k = k - 1; k -= 1; k--).

Don't know where can be the issue.

```
int main(void){
   int height, i, j, k;
   bool check = false;

while (check == false)
{
    height = get_int("Height: ");

    if (height >= 1 && height <= 8)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < height; i++)
        {
            for (k = height -2; k >=0; k--)
            {
                printf(".");
            }
            for (j = 0; j <= i; j++)
            {
                printf("#");
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        check = true;
    }
}}
```

For height 5, this is the target output

```
....#
...##
..###
.####
#####
```

and this is the actual output

```
....#
....##
....###
....#####
....######
```

Comment: Please give us input/output examples.

Comment: `j` loop depends on `i` while `k` loop doesn't. It seems `k` loop should also depend on `i`.

Comment: There is the same number of `'.'` output on every line (`height-1` of them).

Comment: Please also add you Python code ... otherwise we can't compare the differences.

Comment: @Draginko Please use the edit function of the question to add new inforation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second loop `k` needs to be `>= i` and not `>= 0`. I replaced the `get_int` with `5`.

```
int main(void){
int height, i, j, k;
bool check = false;

while (check == false)
{
    height = 5;

    if (height >= 1 && height <= 8)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < height; i++)
        {
          for (k = height -2; k >= i; k--)
          {
            printf(".");
          }
          for (j = 0; j <= i; j++)
          {
            printf("#");
          }
          printf("\n");
    }
    check = true;
}
}}
```

Output:

```
....#                                                                                                                                                                                        
...##                                                                                                                                                                                        
..###                                                                                                                                                                                        
.####                                                                                                                                                                                        
#####
```

Comment: Thanks a lot...I see there are two possible options to solve this, one is to change 0 to i, another one is to initialize k = height -i -2.....what is to difference between them? Or just need to somehow include variable i into the loop?

Comment: If the algorith stays the same .... you may use either approach. Not somehow ... try to understand what you do ;-)

Comment: Yes I try, but I have just started, so my apologise for silly questions..I tought that if I initialise the k = height (eg 5) - 2 +1, it will be decrementing this value by 1 in each “round”, not that it will reinitialised each time

Comment: @Draginko Hi, you may accept my answer if you are ok with it. So this question does not remain open.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `height` never changes as you build your output. You always start with k = 3. How do you expect the number of `.` outputted to change?

Try to use variable `i` when printing out `.`.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the for loop statement to

```
for (k = height - 1; k >=i; k--)
```

k indexing have to start from the 'height' - 1 and ends to i variable.

So for height = 5, the first inner for loop will execute 5 times, when the i increased by one the inner for loop will be executed minus 1 times and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Value of k is decreasing, but the range for which the for loop of k is running is remaining the same as input variable height is not changing. As a result it is always printing 4(height-2+1) dots. To clarify more see this steps:

```
input->height 5 

i = 0, printing four dots for k = 3,2,1,0. printing one '#' for j=0 

i = 1, printing four dots for k = 3,2,1,0. printing two '#' for j=0,1 

i = 2, printing four dots for k = 3,2,1,0. printing three '#' for j=0,1,2 

i = 3, printing four dots for k = 3,2,1,0. printing four '#' for j=0,1,2,3 

i = 4, printing four dots for k = 3,2,1,0. printing five '#' for j=0,1,2,3,4
```

```
for (k = height -i-2; k >=0; k--) //to decrease starting value of k by one each time.
```

```
input->height 5 

i = 0, printing four dots for k = 3,2,1,0. printing one '#' for j=0 

i = 1, printing three dots for k = 2,1,0.  printing two '#' for j=0,1 

i = 2, printing two dots for k = 1,0.      printing three '#' for j=0,1,2 

i = 3, printing one dots for k = 0.        printing four '#' for j=0,1,2,3 

i = 4, printing zero dots for k = .        printing five '#' for j=0,1,2,3,4
```

Answer (score 0):

The posted solution seems more complicated than it could be. You just have to print all the lines up to the requested height and find way to print a *decreasing* number of `'.'` at the beginning of each row.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void draw_triangles(int height, char upper_left, char bottom_right)
{
    if (height < 1  ||  height > 8)
        return;

    for (int row = 0; row < height; ++row)
    {
        // Calculate how many chars are in the left side of each row
        int edge = height - row - 1;
        for ( int i = 0; i < edge; ++i )
            putchar(upper_left);

        for ( int i = edge; i < height; ++i)
            putchar(bottom_right);

        putchar('\n');
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    // Let's test it
    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; ++i)
    {
        printf("%d:\n", i);
        draw_triangles(i, '.', '#');
        puts("");
    }
}
```